# Creating a new class to run game

Tags: class, methods

I have created a class that does Paper Rock Scissors.

```
public class RPS {

    private char cAns;

    public RPS()
    {
        reset();
    }

    public String promptShoot()
    {
        return "Rock, Paper, Scissors, Shoot! (r/p/s)\n";
    }

    public void AI()
    {
        double temp = Math.random();
        int num = (int)(temp * 2.99);

        switch(num) 
        {
            case 0: 
                cAns = 'r';
                break;
            case 1:
                cAns = 'p';
                break;
            case 2:
                cAns = 's';
                break;
        }
    }
```

The class randomly chooses for the computer. and then it asks for the human input using a scanner.

```
    public int shoot(char hAns)
    {
        if(hAns == cAns)
            return 0;
        else if((cAns == 'r' && hAns == 'p')
                || (cAns == 'p' && hAns == 's')
                || (cAns == 's' && hAns == 'r'))
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
```

Once both have chosen their selection, it declares a winner:

```
    public String winner(int won)
    {
        if(won == 1)
            return "The human won!!! All hail the human!!!";
        else if(won == -1)
            return "The computer won!!! Humans must die!!!";
        else
            return "Tie!";
    }

    public void reset()
    {
        cAns = 'a';
    }
}
```

I think this works and all but I did not realize that I needed to create a separate class to run this RPS class.

I have this so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class game
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        RPS choice = new RPS();

        choice.AI();

        System.out.print(choice.promptShoot());
        choice.hAns(scan.nextInt());

        scan.close();
    }
}
```

i thought this would initialize the game but its not working. Any suggestions or can I be pointed in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Add `static` to the `winner` and `shoot` methods.
Put this in main at the end:

```
System.out.println(winner(shoot(scan.nextLine().charAt(0))));
```

Remove `choice.hAns(scan.nextInt());`

Comment: I had my professor help me with the RPS class and apperantly he stated that Im not supposed to change anything on it. It should work the way he gave it to me. Im just supposed to create a class that runs the game. Im just confused since Im new to java..

Comment: Ok there's no way I'm going to rewrite everything but here's how you can fix it: Take everything in main and put it in RPS() after reset(). Then delete everything from main() and put in new RPS(); and you're good to go. There's going to be a few glitches but you'll sort them out quickly.